# jqgrid treeGrid Cannot read property 'rowIndex' of undefined

Tags: jqgrid

I try to use local data with treeGrid, when i click the unfold
    button . I get the tips "Cannot read property 'rowIndex' of
    undefined"

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- The jQuery library is a prerequisite for all jqSuite products -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- This is the Javascript file of jqGrid -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="./js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <!-- This is the localization file of the grid controlling messages, labels, etc.
    <!-- We support more than 40 localizations -->
    <script type="text/ecmascript" src="./js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <!-- A link to a jQuery UI ThemeRoller theme, more than 22 built-in and many more custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" />
    <!-- The link to the CSS that the grid needs -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jqTreeGrid - Load On Demand - Load all Rows at once collapsed</title>
</head>

<body>

    <table id="tree"></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        var rows = [
            {
                "category_id": "1",
                "name": "ELECTRONICS",
                "price": "0.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "1",
                "rgt": "44",
                "level": "0",
                "uiicon": ""
            },
            {
                "category_id": "2",
                "name": "TELEVISIONS",
                "price": "0.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "2",
                "rgt": "19",
                "level": "1",
                "uiicon": ""
            },
            {
                "category_id": "3",
                "name": "TUBE",
                "price": "0.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "3",
                "rgt": "8",
                "level": "2",
                "uiicon": ""
            },
            {
                "category_id": "11",
                "name": "26 \" TV",
                "price": "200.00",
                "qty_onhand": "1",
                "color": "black",
                "lft": "4",
                "rgt": "5",
                "level": "3",
                "uiicon": "ui-icon-image"
            },
            {
                "category_id": "12",
                "name": "30 \" TV",
                "price": "350.00",
                "qty_onhand": "2",
                "color": "black",
                "lft": "6",
                "rgt": "7",
                "level": "3",
                "uiicon": "ui-icon-document"
            },
            {
                "category_id": "4",
                "name": "LCD",
                "price": "0.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "9",
                "rgt": "12",
                "level": "2",
                "uiicon": ""
            },
            {
                "category_id": "13",
                "name": "Super-LCD 42\" ",
                "price": "400.00",
                "qty_onhand": "10",
                "color": "all",
                "lft": "10",
                "rgt": "11",
                "level": "3",
                "uiicon": "ui-icon-video"
            },
            {
                "category_id": "5",
                "name": "PLASMA",
                "price": "0.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "13",
                "rgt": "18",
                "level": "2",
                "uiicon": ""
            },
            {
                "category_id": "14",
                "name": "Ultra-Plasma 62\" ",
                "price": "440.00",
                "qty_onhand": "2",
                "color": "silver",
                "lft": "14",
                "rgt": "15",
                "level": "3",
                "uiicon": "ui-icon-clipboard"
            },
            {
                "category_id": "15",
                "name": "Value Plasma 38\" ",
                "price": "312.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "silver",
                "lft": "16",
                "rgt": "17",
                "level": "3",
                "uiicon": "ui-icon-clipboard"
            },
            {
                "category_id": "6",
                "name": "PORTABLE ELECTRONICS",
                "price": "0.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "20",
                "rgt": "43",
                "level": "1",
                "uiicon": ""
            },
            {
                "category_id": "7",
                "name": "MP3 PLAYERS",
                "price": "0.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "21",
                "rgt": "32",
                "level": "2",
                "uiicon": ""
            },
            {
                "category_id": "8",
                "name": "FLASH",
                "price": "0.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "22",
                "rgt": "29",
                "level": "3",
                "uiicon": ""
            },
            {
                "category_id": "17",
                "name": "Super-Shuffle 1gb",
                "price": "20.00",
                "qty_onhand": "11",
                "color": "all",
                "lft": "23",
                "rgt": "24",
                "level": "4",
                "uiicon": "ui-icon-note"
            },
            {
                "category_id": "21",
                "name": "5Gb Flash",
                "price": "0.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "25",
                "rgt": "26",
                "level": "4",
                "uiicon": "ui-icon-comment"
            },
            {
                "category_id": "22",
                "name": "10Gb  flash ",
                "price": "0.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "27",
                "rgt": "28",
                "level": "4",
                "uiicon": "ui-icon-tag"
            },
            {
                "category_id": "16",
                "name": " Power-MP3 128mb",
                "price": "123.00",
                "qty_onhand": "2",
                "color": "withe",
                "lft": "30",
                "rgt": "31",
                "level": "3",
                "uiicon": "ui-icon-signal-diag"
            },
            {
                "category_id": "9",
                "name": "CD PLAYERS",
                "price": "0.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "33",
                "rgt": "38",
                "level": "2",
                "uiicon": ""
            },
            {
                "category_id": "18",
                "name": " Porta CD ",
                "price": "10.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "34",
                "rgt": "35",
                "level": "3",
                "uiicon": "ui-icon-eject"
            },
            {
                "category_id": "19",
                "name": "CD To go!",
                "price": "110.00",
                "qty_onhand": "11",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "36",
                "rgt": "37",
                "level": "3",
                "uiicon": "ui-icon-power"
            },
            {
                "category_id": "10",
                "name": "2 WAY RADIOS",
                "price": "0.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "39",
                "rgt": "42",
                "level": "2",
                "uiicon": ""
            },
            {
                "category_id": "20",
                "name": "Family Talk 360 ",
                "price": "200.00",
                "qty_onhand": "15",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "40",
                "rgt": "41",
                "level": "3",
                "uiicon": "ui-icon-volume-on"
            },
            {
                "category_id": "23",
                "name": "COMPUTERS",
                "price": "0.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "45",
                "rgt": "50",
                "level": "0",
                "uiicon": ""
            },
            {
                "category_id": "25",
                "name": "DESKTOP ",
                "price": "0.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "46",
                "rgt": "47",
                "level": "1",
                "uiicon": ""
            },
            {
                "category_id": "26",
                "name": "LAPTOPS",
                "price": "0.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "48",
                "rgt": "49",
                "level": "1",
                "uiicon": ""
            },
            {
                "category_id": "24",
                "name": "APPLIANCES",
                "price": "0.00",
                "qty_onhand": "0",
                "color": "",
                "lft": "51",
                "rgt": "52",
                "level": "0",
                "uiicon": ""
            }
        ]



        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            jQuery('#tree').jqGrid({
                // "url":"data.json",
                "colModel": [
                    {
                        "name": "category_id",
                        "index": "accounts.account_id",
                        "sorttype": "int",
                        "key": true,
                        "hidden": true,
                        "width": 50
                    }, {
                        "name": "name",
                        "index": "name",
                        "sorttype": "string",
                        "label": "Name",
                        "width": 170
                    }, {
                        "name": "price",
                        "index": "price",
                        "sorttype": "numeric",
                        "label": "Price",
                        "width": 90,
                        "align": "right"
                    }, {
                        "name": "qty_onhand",
                        "index": "qty_onhand",
                        "sorttype": "int",
                        "label": "Qty",
                        "width": 90,
                        "align": "right"
                    }, {
                        "name": "color",
                        "index": "color",
                        "sorttype": "string",
                        "label": "Color",
                        "width": 100
                    }, {
                        "name": "lft",
                        "hidden": true
                    }, {
                        "name": "rgt",
                        "hidden": true
                    }, {
                        "name": "level",
                        "hidden": true
                    }, {
                        "name": "uiicon",
                        "hidden": true
                    }
                ],
                "width": "780",
                "hoverrows": false,
                "viewrecords": false,
                "gridview": true,
                "height": "auto",
                "sortname": "lft",
                "loadonce": true,
                "rowNum": 100,
                "scrollrows": true,
                // enable tree grid
                "treeGrid": true,
                // which column is expandable
                "ExpandColumn": "name",
                // datatype
                "treedatatype": "json",
                // the model used
                "treeGridModel": "nested",

                // configuration of the data comming from server
                "treeReader": {
                    "left_field": "lft",
                    "right_field": "rgt",
                    "level_field": "level",
                    "leaf_field": "isLeaf",
                    "expanded_field": "expanded",
                    "loaded": "loaded",
                    "icon_field": "icon"
                },
                // "sortorder": "asc",
                "datatype": "local",
                "data": rows,
                "pager": "#pager"
            });


        });




    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is it an answer on your question? You should click on "edit" link below the text of your question to edit the text or to add any additional information to the question. You should additionally always write the **version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and the **fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Comment: It's unclear additionally how you want to load the nodes of the TreeGrid? The code contains commented `"url":"data.json"` and `"datatype": "local", "data": rows` and you use `"treedatatype": "json"`. How you want to load the data: from local `rows` or from the server via Ajax request to load JSON data? If `rows` contains **full data** and you don't want to load nodes on demand then you should include `"loaded": true` property in every item of data.

Answer (score 0):

For localdata type, you must configure the `localReader` parameter:

```
localReader: {
   repeatitems: true,
   // cell: "",
   id: "category_id"
}
```